Proper Difference-in-Difference Model for Time Variant Groups
Take the following example... I have two areas: Area A and Area B. Area A are individuals in a geographic area who are exposed to a health intervention. The health intervention is applied to the entire Area A. Area B is a geographical area that is not exposed to the intervention. We are measuring the outcome rate at baseline and subsequently over the next three years. Ultimately, we want to test whether the intervention reduce the outcome rate by some percentage.
However, to obtain our outcome rates, we are getting data from a sample of the population in the geographical areas. This sample changes through time (i.e., people measured for outcome at baseline may or may not be measured in subsequent time periods). Therefore, it is expected that distributions of demographics will vary through time. For example, at baseline average age could be 60 years, but at one-year the average age could be 58 years.
We know the demographics (age, race, gender) that can change through time depending on the sample are associated with the outcome rate. And they are also likely associated with living in certain areas. Thus they are confounders.
What is the most statistically valid way to quantify the change in the outcome due to the intervention in a difference-in-difference analysis? Given the stage of the project, I would need a strong reason to not have methods that are related to a difference-in-difference methodology.

Are you taking random samples in each year and in each of the respective areas?

@ThomasBilach I wouldn't call them random samples since these are individuals who are going to health facilities to receive care. Some patients may be observed in multiple time periods, some may only be observed once.
